# Amazon Cognito error from android studio (java)

Tags: java, android, amazon-cognito

I am trying to call an Amazon Lambda function from my android app using java.  I get this error:

com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Unable to resolve host "cognito-identity.us-east-1.amazonaws.com": No address associated with hostname

I guess there is something wrong with my Cognito configuration but I am not sure, I followed Amazon's directions. What could I be missing? Thanks!